# Python 3.9.1 & PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

the query I used;

```
s_ekle = nk.lne_sorumlu.text ()
mycurs.execute ("insert into responsible1 (responsible_name) values (% s)", (s_ekle))
QMessageBox.information (anaPen, "Info", f "{s_ekle}\nAdded to database")
MyConn.commit ()
```

the error i got:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

what is the problem?

Comment: What Python driver are you using? Two issues I see; 1) `% s` should be `%s`. 2) `(s_ekle)` should be `(s_ekle,)`. In Python a tuple with a single element needs a comma after the element to distinguish it from a bracketed expression.

Comment: Python 3.9.1 kullanıyorum. tam kodum şu şekilde;def _sorumluEkle():
       try:
              s_ekle = nk.lne_sorumlu.text()
              mycurs.execute("INSERT INTO sorumlu1(sorumlu_adi) VALUES (%s)",s_ekle)
              QMessageBox.information(anaPen,"Bilgi",f"{s_ekle}\nSorumlu Veritabanına eklendi")
              MyConn.commit()

       except Exception as Hata:
              nk.statusbar.showMessage("Hata : "+str(Hata),5000)
              logger.error("Hata : %s",exc_info=True)